# WebSocket Client implementation using a gsm module on an embedded system

Tags: c, websocket, embedded, gsm

I have an embedded device that has a gsm module(Quectel M95F). I can create socket connections and use HTTP Rest API using the module's AT command set. Now I'm trying to implement a WebSocket client application but I couldn't find a test server that is working without the SSL.

WebSocket.org has an echo service, it works well with the browser but it is not possible to connect to it without the SSL. This is the page of that example:
http://www.websocket.org/echo.html

I can not even make the handshake request with GET method on my GSM module. Are there any tips I need to know while I'm trying to get it work with this kind of module? I only found an Arduino Library but it is way too far from my system. I tried to watch the packets sent and received on my browser for that echo server. Then I tried to send the Hand Shake packet using the POSTMAN but I'm always getting Bad Request error.

Comment: Do you want to implement SSL/TLS to your embedded device or you're asking about websocket echo servers without encryption?

Answer (score 0):

ws://echo.websocket.org works without SSL, this is my example page:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<title>WebSocket Test</title>

<script>
var wsServ = "ws://echo.websocket.org";

function initWebSockets()
{
    websocket = new WebSocket(wsServ);
}
 
window.addEventListener("load", initWebSockets, false);
</script>
```

And this is server response:

```
HTTP/1.1 101 Web Socket Protocol Handshake
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
Access-Control-Allow-Headers: content-type, authorization, x-websocket-extensions, x-websocket-version, x-websocket-protocol
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null
Connection: Upgrade
Date: Tue, 18 Jul 2017 22:06:46 GMT
Sec-WebSocket-Accept: qn0lFK1Dg0wZ4esiqXliCDB2lTg=
Server: Kaazing Gateway
Upgrade: websocket
```

Also this is my request headers:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: echo.websocket.org
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:54.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/54.0
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.5
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Origin: null
Sec-WebSocket-Extensions: permessage-deflate
Sec-WebSocket-Key: av25rwzrdCw9qTswx7bmTA==
Connection: keep-alive, Upgrade
Pragma: no-cache
Cache-Control: no-cache
Upgrade: websocket
```

The WebSocket Protocol specification ([RFC 6455](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6455)) suggest strictly enforcing handshake (HTTP traffic) format for security reasons, it will be better if you compare your traffic with suggested type.